# How to display a leafletjs overlay image with geojson type MultiPolygon

Tags: image, leaflet, overlay, geojson

I am trying to add an image overlay on a map using data provided to me in a geoJSON file.
geoJSON:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "TITLE": "WENCHANG PALACE",
                "VISIBLE": 1,
                "DESCRIPTIO": null,
                "IMAGE_URL": "https://vanderbilt365-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/stacy_e_curry_vanderbilt_edu/EQCL9HPHxhRCqMOmHZOi5FgB3ZzE2s9W8jHfOs7HJ0W9qQ?e=y9Qx4s",
                "IMAGE_LINK": null,
                "DATE": "1899-12-30",
                "TYPEID": 0
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                112.436225146264263,
                                37.708843845019551
                            ],
                            [
                                112.436070905529988,
                                37.708525529245208
                            ],
                            [
                                112.43637669205269,
                                37.708432144987704
                            ],
                            [
                                112.43653219042838,
                                37.708752593215998
                            ],
                            [
                                112.436225146264263,
                                37.708843845019551
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to adapt this example (https://leafletjs.com/examples/overlays/), but I can not get my image to display. How do I use the data in the geoJSON file to create the correct lat/long for the image?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qa0wn1fL/1/
I have a polygon where I would like the image to be, but when I add the following code my image does not show up, no errors, but no image:

```
var imageUrl = 'https://iiif.library.vanderbilt.edu/iiif/2/attcat%2Fwenchang.jpg/full/!1000,1000/0/default.jpg';
var errorOverlayUrl = 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/110/110686.png';
var altText = 'Image of Newark, N.J. in 1922. Source: The University of Texas at Austin, UT Libraries Map Collection.';
var latLngBounds = L.latLngBounds([
  [112.43607090552999, 37.70852552924521],
  [112.43622514626426, 37.70884384501955]
]);
var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, latLngBounds, {
  opacity: 0.8,
  errorOverlayUrl,
  alt: altText,
  interactive: true
});
```

I'm not sure how to translate the data from the MultiPolygon be correct for the lat/lng for the image overlay.

Comment: Seems to be missing an `.addTo(map)`

Comment: Good point, sadly it does not fix the issue. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qa0wn1fL/1/

Comment: See https://macwright.com/lonlat/

Comment: As far as I can tell the lon/lat are correct. After all, they are used to draw the red rectangle where the image is supposed to appear.

Comment: And actually you are indeed correct IvanSanchez, sorry for my earlier response.